# Mostrar resultado de Promesa con Axios en Vue

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, wordpress-api

Estoy practicando el uso de Axios en Vue para consumir la API de WP y tratando de recuperar los item del menu de navegacion, pero cuando corro la pagina, se me muestra solo el objeto [object Promise], imagino que no la estoy resolviendo o la estoy aplicando mal, tengo mas o menos esto

```
//menu.js
import axios from 'axios';

export const links = {   
   async getLinks() {
      let url = 'http://localhost:8090/php-headless-wp/wordpress/wp-json/myroutes/menu';
      axios
      .get(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .catch(error => error);
    }
};
```

Luego en un archivo aparte trato de hacer la llamada a la API

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    {{menu}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {links} from './menu.js';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data () {
    return {
      menu: links.getLinks(),
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Al acceder directamente la URL de la API tengo el JSON siguiente

```json
[
{
"ID": 18,
"post_author": "1",
"post_date": "2022-05-01 18:22:33",
"post_date_gmt": "2022-05-01 16:45:01",
"post_content": " ",
"post_title": "",
"post_excerpt": "",
"post_status": "publish",
"comment_status": "closed",
"ping_status": "closed",
"post_password": "",
"post_name": "18",
"to_ping": "",
"pinged": "",
"post_modified": "2022-05-01 18:22:33",
"post_modified_gmt": "2022-05-01 18:22:33",
"post_content_filtered": "",
"post_parent": 0,
"guid": "http://localhost:8090/php-headless-wp/wordpress/?p=18",
"menu_order": 1,
"post_type": "nav_menu_item",
"post_mime_type": "",
"comment_count": "0",
"filter": "raw",
"db_id": 18,
"menu_item_parent": "0",
"object_id": "2",
"object": "page",
"type": "post_type",
"type_label": "Page",
"url": "http://localhost:8090/php-headless-wp/wordpress/",
"title": "Home",
"target": "",
"attr_title": "",
"description": "",
"classes": [
""
],
"xfn": ""
},
{
"ID": 19,
"post_author": "1",
"post_date": "2022-05-01 18:22:33",
"post_date_gmt": "2022-05-01 16:45:02",
"post_content": " ",
"post_title": "",
"post_excerpt": "",
"post_status": "publish",
"comment_status": "closed",
"ping_status": "closed",
"post_password": "",
"post_name": "19",
"to_ping": "",
"pinged": "",
"post_modified": "2022-05-01 18:22:33",
"post_modified_gmt": "2022-05-01 18:22:33",
"post_content_filtered": "",
"post_parent": 0,
"guid": "http://localhost:8090/php-headless-wp/wordpress/?p=19",
"menu_order": 2,
"post_type": "nav_menu_item",
"post_mime_type": "",
"comment_count": "0",
"filter": "raw",
"db_id": 19,
"menu_item_parent": "0",
"object_id": "8",
"object": "page",
"type": "post_type",
"type_label": "Page",
"url": "http://localhost:8090/php-headless-wp/wordpress/about/",
"title": "About",
"target": "",
"attr_title": "",
"description": "",
"classes": [
""
],
"xfn": ""
},
{
"ID": 78,
"post_author": "1",
"post_date": "2022-05-01 18:22:33",
"post_date_gmt": "2022-05-01 18:22:04",
"post_content": "",
"post_title": "Episodes",
"post_excerpt": "",
"post_status": "publish",
"comment_status": "closed",
"ping_status": "closed",
"post_password": "",
"post_name": "episodes",
"to_ping": "",
"pinged": "",
"post_modified": "2022-05-01 18:22:33",
"post_modified_gmt": "2022-05-01 18:22:33",
"post_content_filtered": "",
"post_parent": 0,
"guid": "http://localhost:8090/php-headless-wp/wordpress/?p=78",
"menu_order": 3,
"post_type": "nav_menu_item",
"post_mime_type": "",
"comment_count": "0",
"filter": "raw",
"db_id": 78,
"menu_item_parent": "0",
"object_id": "4",
"object": "category",
"type": "taxonomy",
"type_label": "Category",
"url": "http://localhost:8090/php-headless-wp/wordpress/category/episodes/",
"title": "Episodes",
"target": "",
"attr_title": "",
"description": "",
"classes": [
""
],
"xfn": ""
},
{
"ID": 79,
"post_author": "1",
"post_date": "2022-05-01 18:22:33",
"post_date_gmt": "2022-05-01 18:22:33",
"post_content": "",
"post_title": "Blog",
"post_excerpt": "",
"post_status": "publish",
"comment_status": "closed",
"ping_status": "closed",
"post_password": "",
"post_name": "blog",
"to_ping": "",
"pinged": "",
"post_modified": "2022-05-01 18:22:33",
"post_modified_gmt": "2022-05-01 18:22:33",
"post_content_filtered": "",
"post_parent": 0,
"guid": "http://localhost:8090/php-headless-wp/wordpress/?p=79",
"menu_order": 4,
"post_type": "nav_menu_item",
"post_mime_type": "",
"comment_count": "0",
"filter": "raw",
"db_id": 79,
"menu_item_parent": "0",
"object_id": "5",
"object": "category",
"type": "taxonomy",
"type_label": "Category",
"url": "http://localhost:8090/php-headless-wp/wordpress/category/blog/",
"title": "Blog",
"target": "",
"attr_title": "",
"description": "",
"classes": [
""
],
"xfn": ""
},
{
"ID": 23,
"post_author": "1",
"post_date": "2022-05-01 18:22:33",
"post_date_gmt": "2022-05-01 16:45:25",
"post_content": " ",
"post_title": "",
"post_excerpt": "",
"post_status": "publish",
"comment_status": "closed",
"ping_status": "closed",
"post_password": "",
"post_name": "23",
"to_ping": "",
"pinged": "",
"post_modified": "2022-05-01 18:22:33",
"post_modified_gmt": "2022-05-01 18:22:33",
"post_content_filtered": "",
"post_parent": 0,
"guid": "http://localhost:8090/php-headless-wp/wordpress/?p=23",
"menu_order": 5,
"post_type": "nav_menu_item",
"post_mime_type": "",
"comment_count": "0",
"filter": "raw",
"db_id": 23,
"menu_item_parent": "0",
"object_id": "16",
"object": "page",
"type": "post_type",
"type_label": "Page",
"url": "http://localhost:8090/php-headless-wp/wordpress/contact/",
"title": "Contact",
"target": "",
"attr_title": "",
"description": "",
"classes": [
""
],
"xfn": ""
}
]
```

Comment: getlinks no devuelve nada de nada.. que esperas que tenga menu? te recomiendo, antes de tratar de encapsular axios, usarlo directamente en tu componente vue para que entiendas como funciona... aca, hay que reescribir todo lo que hiciste con axios... segui los ejemplos triviales de la pagina y te va a salir... Ah, y wp, aca, nada que ver.. tu problema no es esa api... tendrias el mismo problema con cualquier otra api...

Answer (score 0):

Logre resolverlo, hubiera esperado una guia mas certera, se les agradece la lectura, entonces quedo asi, devolviendo la promesa del fetch de axios

```
//menu.js
import axios from 'axios';

export const links = {
   async getLinks() {
      let url = 'http://localhost:8090/php-headless-wp/wordpress/wp-json/myroutes/menu';
      
      let resp =  await axios
                            .get(url)
                            .then(res => res.data)
                            .catch(error => error);
      
      return resp;
    }
};
```

Entonces mi error es asumir que la promesa se resuelve en el valor retornado, pero no lo es, la promesa retornada igual se tiene que resolver primero para utilizar, el archivo app.vue quedaria asi entonces

```
<script>
import {links} from './menu.js';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data () {
    return {
      menu: [],
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    let res = links.getLinks();
    let getMenu = () => {
      res.then(result => {
        this.menu = result;
      });
    };
    
    getMenu();
  }
}
</script>
```